# Validar duplicidad de datos con data annotation

Tags: mvc

tengo una tabla en bd sql sever llamado articulo con los campos
`IdArticulo, CodArticulo, DesArticulo, IsActivo`...en mi proyecto mvc valido casi todos los campos con `data.annotation`...por ejem `IdArticulo` con , `CodArticulo` con ...pero no se como validar el campo `CodArticulo` que es unique en la BD...Por ejem yo ingreso un item de esta forma:

```
IdArticulo   CodArticulo   DesArticulo   IsActivo
   1            A001      GALLETA SODA      1
```

Hasta ahi todo bien...pero si yo deseo ingresar otro item con el mismo código (A001)...como podria con `data.annotation` verificar que se esta ingresando un registro duplicado?

Recuerden que el campo CodArticulo es unique y al validar deberia retornar un

> ErrorMessage:="Ya existe un item con el mismo codigo"

Espero su ayuda.

Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Amigo el problema en este caso es que necesitas validar datos que estan en BD por lo que obligatoriamente debes hacer una consulta para revisar si existe ya en tu base de datos. Puedes en tu controlador, al llamar el método POST validar si ya existe. ejemplo:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include="IdArticulo, CodArticulo, DesArticulo, IsActivo")] Articulo articulo)
{

    if (db.Articulos.Any(a => a.CodArticulo == articulo.CodArticulo))
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("CodArticulo", "Ya existe un artículo con este código");
    }
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Articulos.Add(articulo);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return View(articulo);
}
```

como puedes ver antes de la condición para Guardar el Artículo agregué otra condición en la que pregunto si ya existe un artículo en bd con ese código, de ser así llamo a  `ModelState.AddModelError()` y le paso como parámetros el campo a validar("CodArticulo") y el mensaje que quiero mostrar "....". De esta forma validas, espero te sea de ayuda

Comment: ok...entiendo...pero todo este proceso se da al dar click en el boton enviar...es ahi justo cuando debe de hacer la validacion...el que inserta el registro es el controlador llamado Create() que conecta a la pc y hace la insercion...la pregunta es...en que parte del controlador llamo al codigo que me muestras???

Comment: perdon...era conecta a la BD

Comment: Si estas creando un Artículo debe ir en el método Create de tipo POST del controlador Artículos, tal y como te lo he mostrado en la respuesta

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacer uso de Remote y añadir acciones de un controlador.
Adjunto enlace de microsoft:

https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-8.0

y código de ejemplo:

```
[Remote(action: "VerifyName", controller: "Users", AdditionalFields = nameof(LastName))]
[Display(Name = "First Name")]
public string FirstName { get; set; } = null!;
```